DMS replication task fails due to a corrupt binlog event
I have a mariadb RDS database deployed as a multi-AZ in my AWS account, engine version 10.6.16. This DB serves as the main backend database serving ~100 connections per second. I also have a DMS replication task running in my account that connects my RDS into a kinesis stream. Recently that task have been failing with this error, that I am having trouble finding any information on:
Read next binary log event failed; mariadb_rpl_fetch error 1236 (Failed to replace GTID event with backwards-compatible event: corrupt event.; 
the first event 'mysql-bin-changelog.034769' at 28382, the last event read from 'mysql-bin-changelog.034990' at 16922132, the last byte read from 'mysql-bin-changelog.034990' at 16922174.) [1020403]  (mysql_endpoint_capture.c:1163)

Resuming the task doesnt produce any results, just immediately fails, which is kind of expected since there seem to be a corrupted binglog event in the DB. After restating the DMS task though I got the same exact error but now mysql-bin-changelog values were different, so seems like a corrupted event at a different point.
I found this code in the mariadb source code that seems to be the source of the error, but I dont understand how db engines work enough to be able to understand what i need to do to fix this.
Running show slave status produces no results, also the only thing I noticed that was out of normal is BinLogDiskUsage metric seems to have jumped from ~2GB to 5GB in the span of couple of days pretty much at the same time as I got that error

take a look at MDEV-33849 but feel free to do your own bug report. The private ftp server was having hardware trouble so might be offline.

While I wasn't able to fix the issue with my transactions not loading into DMS, I was able to find out the reason why transactions were corrupted, which turned out to be a legitimate bug on our app level. Some transactions related to a worker periodic task were corrupted because the worker instance would run out of memory and transaction couldn't close correctly. After addressing the bug on app-level I cleared out the binlog and this didnt happen anymore
